# jQuery hide extra borders list items

Tags: html, css

my code looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/eLyJA/

how can I calculate and remove all edge of borders, so it look like this: 
[image]

Comment: This can be done with just CSS. No javascript required.

Comment: I can't see a question, only links. :(

Comment: I enjoy the picture though. And also I agree with @ahren. There is no need in JavaScript here.

Comment: Great; now I want to play noughts-and-crosses (or tic-tac-toe). And how does the JS Fiddle demo relate to that picture? Where's the 'block' meant to be, in the above picture

Comment: This is simple with CSS, no Javascript needed

Comment: @Brendan - let's see it!

Comment: @Brendan Come on man, give a shot!

Comment: @Wex I would, not from a phone though; hence the comment instead of answer.

Comment: Does it need to be an unordered list, as in your link?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

used for loop to achieve this: http://jsfiddle.net/eLyJA/15/

```
var total = $("ul li").size();

$().ready(function () {
    for( i=2; i < total ; i+=3){
        $('ul li:nth-child(' + i + ')').each(function(n) {
            $(this).css({
                'border-right': '1px solid #000',
                'border-bottom': '1px solid #000',
                'border-left': '1px solid #000'
            });
        });
    }

    j = total;
    k = total - 3;
    for( j=total ; j > total-3; j--){
        $('ul li:nth-child(' + j + ')').each(function(n) {
            $(this).css({
                'border-bottom': 'none'
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Any reason why you "don't like table"? Is it tabular data?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: I also discovered a fairly decent cross-browser "hack" to get the solution working in older versions of IE.**

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/n1ck/p3SCR/4/**

I added, to my previous solution:

```
table {
    border-color:transparent; 
    border-style:solid; 
}

table td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

---

You can achieve this two ways, here in CSS:

http://jsfiddle.net/eLyJA/3/

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td {
    padding:80px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
table tr:first-child td {
    border-top: 0;
}
table tr:last-child td {
    border-bottom: 0;
}
table tr td:first-child{
    border-left: 0;
}
table tr td:last-child,
    border-right: 0;
}​
```

Here, by setting the table `frame="void"`

http://jsfiddle.net/eLyJA/7/

```
<table border="1" frame="void">
```

Comment: Yeah, IE may damage the solution... as usual.

Comment: Solid solution. Keep in mind [`:last-child`](http://caniuse.com/#search=last-child) only works in IE9+. Never even heard of the attribute [`frame`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/table/frame), but that might be a better solution with IE8+ compatibility.

Comment: `frame="void"` doesn't seem to work as expected in IE8. I have however found a solution which works in IE8: http://jsfiddle.net/n1ck/p3SCR/1